# postgres replace isnull with integer

Tags: sql, postgresql, isnull

I am trying to replace empty cells in a column (type int) with an integer.

I am using Postgres. I have been able to replace them in a 'select' query using coalesce, but not sure how to alter the records permanently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an `update` statement:

```
UPDATE my_table
SET    my_int_column = 0
WHERE  my_int_column IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

This does not answer your question. However, this does the opposite. So, in case someone is looking up for replacing a value with `NULL` in `select` query result and reached this post, use the `nullif` function:

```
select last_name||', '||first_name as "Name", nullif(salary, 0) as "Salary" from employee;
```

Here, it will return all records including records where salary is zero, but will show empty cells in place of zero.